# Comparing Key Values in an Object using an isBetween functions

Tags: javascript, object

I am having trouble comparing key values in a JavaScript object. The only way I know how to check values is using a (for in) loop and that doesn't seem to be of any help here:

```
var brackets = {
    "39.6": 415050,
    "33": 413350,
    "28": 190150,
    "25": 91150,
    "15": 37650,
    "10": 9275,
};

function isBetween(num){
    // just an example

    if (num < 413350 && num > 190150) 
        return "28";

}
```

**Edit**:

If `num` is between two values the return value should be the key of the lower bound

Comment: `if (num < 413350 && num > 190150) return 28;` ? Or expand your question a bit more

Comment: If `num` is between two values the return value should be the key of the lower bound?

Comment: @Andreas yes exactly, thanks for wording that succinctly

Comment: Since `num > 190150` and the value of `28` is `190150`, Why return `28`?  Or should `num >= 190150` ?

Comment: For `lower bound`, I think the range should be `[first, last)`, namely [190150, 413350)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isBetween(num) {
    var sortedKeys = Object.keys(brackets) // get all keys
        .map(Number)                       // make them Numbers
        .sort(function (a, b) {            // sort them as the order isn't guaranteed
            return a == b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);
        });

    for (var i = 0, l = sortedKeys.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
        if (num > brackets[sortedKeys[i]] && num < brackets[sortedKeys[i + 1]]) {
            return sortedKeys[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avfastmf/)

Returns the key of the lower bound or `undefined`

The part with sorting the keys may not be necessary but as the order of the elements in an object isn't guaranteed I've added this step as well.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient way. I was just think if interchanging the key and value can lead to a better snippet

```
var brackets = {
        "39.6": 415050,
        "33": 413350,
        "28": 190150,
        "25": 91150,
        "15": 37650,
        "10": 9275,
    };

function isBetween(num) {    
    var x = brackets;
    var bsNum;
    var tempArray = []
    for (key in x) {            //Get the values 
        tempArray.push(x[key]);
    }
   for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {   //use tempArray array to find the range
        if (num > tempArray[i] && num < tempArray[i + 1]) {
            bsNum = tempArray[i + 1];
            break;
        } else if (num < tempArray[i]) { // if number is less than 9275
            bsNum = tempArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    for (key in x) {
        if (bsNum == x[key]) {
            console.log(key)
        }
    }
}
isBetween(9274);
isBetween(413349);
isBetween(37659);
isBetween(91100);
isBetween(190150);

isBetween(415050);
isBetween(413300);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qm37d73p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

With lodash [`_.keysIn`](https://lodash.com/docs#keysIn) and [`_.min`](https://lodash.com/docs#min). We can get the key of the lower bound of `[190150, 413350)`.

```
_.min( _.keysIn( brackets, function(e) { 
     return ((e < 413350 ) && (e >= 190150)); 
}));
```

`keysIn` returns all keys in the range of `[190150, 413350)`, and `min` get the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with flipped object:

```
var flipped = {}, prop, vals = [];
for (prop in brackets){
    flipped[brackets[prop]] = prop;
    vals.push(brackets[prop]);
}

function isBetween(num){
    for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
       if(num >= vals[i] && num < vals[i+1]){
           return flipped[vals[i]];   
       } 
    }
    return false;
}

var num = 414000;
console.log(isBetween(num));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(brackets,function(k,v){
   return ((parseInt(v) < 413350) && (parseInt(v) > 190150)) ? 28 : false;
});
```

Comment: this is wrong logic, use if first than search for lower value in brackets error.

Comment: This is completely useless as the return value of the callback only indicates if the loop should continue (anything but `false`) or not (`false`)